# Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin (KPSS) and Augmented Dickey–Fuller (ADF) Tests

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test, example

I have been searching for a sample usage of the KPSS and ADF tests, however I can only find pages reporting examples using R or Python. The mathematical definition of the KPSS test also seems to be pretty hard to find and I would love to see it. My question is: can you showcase a very simple but complete example of how to perform/compute the KPSS and ADF tests on a toy time series in plain math, without any programming language?

Comment: I am bit confused... like you want to do it on some toy data all just by hand, or you just want the math derivation or do you want code that will do that without a use of specific package?

Comment: @1muflon1 The first option ("you want to do it on some toy data all just by hand") is what I initially meant, however if you can also add the rest I would really appreciate it, especially the code without using specific packages, but also the math derivation.